# Where is [NSIndexPath row] documented?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can anyone point me to where [indexPath row] is described in the documentation, I have looked at NSIndexPath but I can't find any mention of "row"? I am assuming its an NSUInteger, but I would also like to double check its type and see what other properties are available.

Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger currentRow = [indexPath row];
}
```

cheers Gary

Comment: Much appreciated for all the answers, many thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `.row` property is part of the extension category defined in UIKit.

The doc is in https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsindexpath/1614853-row (row) and https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsindexpath/1528298-section (section).

> ### row
>
> An index number identifying a row in a section of a table view. (read-only)
>
> ```
> @property(readonly) NSUInteger row
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> The section the row is in is identified by the value of `section`.

---

The Swift counterpart: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath/1779554-row (row) and https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath/1779112-section (section).

These Swift properties are of type `Int`.

Comment: saved my life. suddenly .row, .section wasn't available.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the [`NSIndexPath(UITableView)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a UIKit addition, which is documented [separately](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html). You're correct in that it's an `NSUInteger`.

Comment: Yeah, and for some reason those UIKit additions' docs are really hard to find. I'm always looking for the exact spelling of the string drawing-size methods in there. Xcode won't autocomplete them, and it always takes me some hunting to find that darn document.